# SonarLint/Visual Studio: A single ruleset for all projects in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

When I connect from VS2015 to SonarQube server using SonarLint, SonarLint starts to download nuget packages and then adds a .ruleset file for each project.

Is it possible to have only one ruleset defined for the solution (the one from here SonarQube/CSharp.ruleset) and only when needed to create specific ruleset files for project?

I saw the question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287221/sonarqube-sonarlint-visual-studio-use-one-ruleset-fo-all-projects-in-solution) but is as year old and maybe someone found a workaround for this (I have mainly C# projects and the same ruleset applies to all the projects).

Comment: Talked with another team that is using VS with SonarLint and they have edited each csproj file to point to the general one:
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\SonarQube\Project.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>

Answer (score 1):

If you have allready set a ruleset-file (e.g. a single one for all your projects within the solution) and then start the syncronisation with sonar cube new rulesets will be set to each project, thats correct.

But looking within these files they are only include-refrences to your old single-refrence and to the new (also single) sonar-reference.

As a result the behaviour of your single-ruleset doesn't change!